# Need help with associative arrays

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

My brain is fried after 10 hours of coding, so I need some help.

I have used the following function to retrieve data from a form submission (before I process the data, verifying input etc):

```
  // All form fields are identified by '[id]_[name]', where 'id' is the 
  // identifier of the form type. Eg. brand, store etc.
  // The field identifier we want to return is just the name and not the id.
  public function getFormData() {
    $formData = array();
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
      $name = preg_replace('!.*_!', '', $key);
      if (is_array($value)) {
        $formData[$name] = implode(',', $value);
      } else {
        $formData[$name] = $value;
      }
    }
    return $formData;
  }
```

Now I'm submitting the form using AJAX, so I'm not able to use this function any more.

My $_POST['formData'] string looks like this (short version):

```
"store_name=My+new+store&store_street1=Some+address&store_zipcode=1188"
```

My goal is to be able to execute the following code:

```
echo $formData['name'] //Displays 'Some address'
```

My jQuery code looks like this:

```
  function processRegistration()
  {

    var formData = jQuery('#registerStore form').serialize();

    jQuery.post("mypath/jquery_bll.php", { instance: 'processRegistration', formData : formData },
      function(data)
      {
          alert('some test data here');
      },"json");
```

How can I change my function to handle data from an Ajax call?

Comment: Why do you think that just because the request is coming in via an AJAX request you can't use your function?

Comment: May I ask what { instance:'processRegistration' ...  is for?

Comment: @andho - I'm using a lot of jQuery which needs to call some PHP code. Instead of having one file for each jQuery call, I'm using just one php file. But in order execute the right function within the file, I need an identifier. 'processRegistration' is the name of the function to execute the registartion process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice that your using:

```
jQuery.post("mypath/jquery_bll.php", { instance: 'processRegistration', formData : formData },
```

In your code which will most probably output:

```
instance=processRegistration&formData=field1=value1&field2=value2
```

So what the php script will get is:

```
$_POST = array(
  'instance'=>'processRegistration',
  'formData'=>'field1=value1',
  'field2'=>'value2
);
```

**Edit:** This is because the serialized object will create a query string that is ready to be sent and then you are putting it inside an object for the data parameter.
The data parameter either accepts an key/value object or query string from the likes of jquery.fn.serialize.
http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.post
So maybe if you change this line:

```
jQuery.post("mypath/jquery_bll.php", { instance: 'processRegistration', formData : formData },
```

..to ..

```
jQuery.post("mypath/jquery_bll.php", formData + '&instance=processRegistration',
```

that would work

Comment: Yes, correct observed. I just found a page which will help me solve my problem: http://www.frankmaulit.com/2008/06/12/handling-jquery-serialize-on-the-backend-with-php/

Answer (score 3):

If you're using [`$.post()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.post) there is no difference. It's just a POST request.

Comment: Agreed. But $.post is calling jquery_bll.php and adding a POST varaible 'instance'. Thus "foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)" will include the 'instance'. I only want the data from $_POST['formData']. And replacing $_POST with $_POST['formData'] is not working.

Answer (score 0):

There's no functional difference between an ajax call and a regular call from a browser.

So, to answer...

```
$formData = getFormData();
echo $formData['name'];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to using plugins you could use this little plugin although it is not available in the jquery plugin repo

```
$.params2json = function(d) {
    if (d.constructor != Array) {
        return d;
    }
    var data={};
    for(var i=0;i<d.length;i++) {
        if (typeof data[d[i].name] != 'undefined') {
            if (data[d[i].name].constructor!= Array) {
                data[d[i].name]=[data[d[i].name],d[i].value];
            } else {
                data[d[i].name].push(d[i].value);
            }
        } else {
            data[d[i].name]=d[i].value;
        }
    }
    return data;
};
```

You can use the following code with the plugin:

```
function processRegistration()
{
  var formData = $.params2json($('#registerStore form').serializeArray());
  formData.instance = 'processRegistration';
  $.post('mypath/jquery_bll.php', formData,
    function(data) {
      alert('some test data here');
    }, "json");
  });
}
```